# Map drill-down in a cube

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dictionary, data-visualization, ssrs-2008-r2

I use SSRS 2008R2 and my data is in a cube. In my cube I have 3 dimensions:

1. Geographic Dimension with hierarchies (country -> Department -> Towns)
2. Activity with hierarchies (group - > Subgroup -> Family)
3. Time with year

And a Measure: Value

I want to build a report which displays in a map the measure value in function of parameters.

For example: the user can wants to see measure value for a country and a town (geographic dimension) for 1 subgroup or 1 group.

The difficulty is to navigate between the geographic hierarchy and Activities for the same dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Shape File or SQL table with a Geometry column to provide the link between your Geographic Dimension (e.g Country, Department, Town) and your cube data. A SQL table is best as it is common to find data quality issues, you can issue SQL spatial queries (e.g. all Towns within 200km of X) and runtime performance is better.